# How can I make my function more concise by using list comprehension or any other method?

Tags: python, list, function, list-comprehension

context: I have a list of lists and I am trying to get rid of duplicate entries. The list of lists is ordered by the first element in the sublist. When the function encounters the first occurrence of the sublist, the function appends that sublist to the "non_duplicate_list". If the function encounters another sublist with the same first element it continues.

Problem: I have a function that is working perfectly, but I feel it is too long. Is there any way to shorten/make the code more concise? maybe using list comprehension?

Here is the function:

```
def remove_duplicates(data_set):
    non_duplicate_list = []
    for row in data_set:
        app_name = row[0]
        if any(app_name in sublist for sublist in non_duplicate_list):
            continue
        else:
            non_duplicate_list.append(row)
```

I tried doing this to make the function more concise, but it didn't work:

```
def remove_the_dupes(data_set):
    non_duplicate_list = [continue if any(row[0] not in sublist for sublist in non_duplicate_list) else non_duplicate_list.append(row) for row in data_set]
    return non_duplicate_list
```

I then get an error message about wrong syntax

please provide any shortened version of my function if possible. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
 not_duplicate_list = [row for row in datset if not any(row[0] in sublist for sublist in non_duplicate_list)]
```

you shouldn't use `continue` and `return` in a list comprehension, take a look [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension) for more info